# Can I select data across multiple schemas within the same SQL database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, schema

I have one database with multiple schemas. I would like to run `SELECT * FROM info`, across all schemas that starts with "team".

The schemas are not fixed, meaning that schemas are added and dropped continuously, so I can't hardcode the schemas in the query. But I'm only interested in schemas that starts with "team". How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all tables have an identical structure, you can write a PL/pgSQL function that does this:

```
create function get_info(p_schema_prefix text)
  returns table (... column definitions go here ...)
as
$$
declare
  l_rec record;
  l_sql text;
begin
  for l_rec in select table_schema, table_name
               from information_schema.tables
               where table_name = 'info'
                 and table_schema like p_schema_prefix||'%'
  loop 
    l_sql := format('select id, data from %I.%I', l_rec.table_schema, l_rec.table_name);
    return query execute l_sql;
  end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

The use it like this:

```
select *
from get_info('team')
```

Comment: I want to test this first without creating a function. I'm running it in PGAdmin. How much of it do I need to run it, it keeps giving me error.

Comment: @Ben: you can't do this without creating a function. But creating the function will not break anything,  or interfere with any existing code. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f4148fcb35919f8254e61197f83fd37e

Comment: Got it. One last question: first line inside the loop where you say `%I.%I`, how does it know which of the columns to inject first. The reason why I ask this is that I might want to make a more advanced select in the future where I will need to reference the the schema multiple times, what do I do then? And Why do I even need to reference the info table, can I not just hardcode it as it is only the schema name that is dynamic in the loop?

Comment: See the manual for the [format()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function - those are positional parameters

Comment: Aaah okay, and the info table name, could I just hardcode it instead of selecting it and passing it as a parameter? Like this: `'select id, data from %I.info`

Comment: And then of course `for l_rec in select table_schema from...`

Comment: You could test it by creating a temporary function like this: CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.function_name(). Then you're not actually making a schema change in the DB, if you want to be extra cautious you can do this in transaction that you roll back at the end